# MySQL once allowed a CHAR column to FK to another tables ENUM column, but not anymore?

Tags: mysql, enums, foreign-key-relationship

Old computer:  MySQL version 5.0.51

New Computer:  MySQL version 5.7.9

DDL snip:

```
CREATE TABLE lookup (
    keyvalue ENUM ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D') NOT NULL;
    CONTSTRAINT lookuppk PRIMARY KEY (keyvalue)
);

CREATE TABLE othertable (
    otherkey INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    refkey CHAR(1),
    CONSTRAINT otherpk PRIMARY KEY (otherkey),
    CONSTRAINT reffk FOREIGN KEY (refkey) REFERENCES lookup(keyvalue)
);
```

Result when run on old computer:  No problem

Result when run on new computer:  ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

This was an experimental database running only on my home machine, not anything for work or real-life.  I did this originally about four years ago, and I am starting to migrate stuff to a newly purchased home computer.

The error seems to be simply that an FK must match the datatype of the referenced column *exactly*.  In hindsight, this is a bad design, I'm older and wiser and I can change.  But what has me curious is why an older MySQL version allowed this.  I've looked through the documentation but could not find anything.

Comment: There is no engine defined in the CREATE TABLE Statement. look if one is default MyISAM. Then change it ti InnoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Bernd Buffen already mentioned, most probably on your old computer the tables are using the MyISAM engine, which was standard back then. MyISAM silently ignores any specifications about foreign keys cause it didn't and still does not support them. When you alter your tables with

```
ALTER TABLE <table name> ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

you will get the same error on your old computer.

You can also verify this with this query:

```
show variables like '%storage%';
```

In MySQL 5.7 it will probably show:

```
+----------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name              | Value  |
+----------------------------+--------+
| default_storage_engine     | InnoDB |
| default_tmp_storage_engine | InnoDB |
| storage_engine             | InnoDB |
+----------------------------+--------+
```

while on MySQL 5.0 it will show MyISAM.